# Multiple hasmany same keycolumn - illegal access to loading collection

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

it works. pull the data, but gives this error: **illegal access to loading collection**

```
 public class Image : File
    {
        public virtual string ImagePath { get; set; }
    }

    public class Video : File
    {
        public virtual string VideoPath { get; set; }
        public virtual string VideoType { get; set; }
    }


   public class Service : ContentBase
    {
        public virtual IList<Image> Images { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Video> Videos { get; set; }
    }



   public class ServiceMap:SubclassMap<Domain.Service>
    {
        public ServiceMap()
        {
            DiscriminatorValue("Service");

            HasMany(x => x.Images).KeyColumn("ContentBase");
            HasMany(x => x.Videos).KeyColumn("ContentBase");
        }
    }

public class ImageMap:SubclassMap<Image>
    {
        public ImageMap()
        {
            DiscriminatorValue("Image");

            Map(x => x.ImagePath);
        }
    }

 public class VideoMap:SubclassMap<Video>
    {
        public VideoMap()
        {
            DiscriminatorValue("Video");

            Map(x => x.VideoPath);
        }
    }
```

it works. but it gives this error when I query. I think the same "keycolumn" gives this error to be. mapping'i How should I do?

Comment: how are the mappings of Video and image?

Comment: var service = UnitOfWork.CurrentSession.QueryOver<Domain.Service>()
                .JoinAlias(x => x.ThumbImage, () => thumbImage)
                .JoinAlias(x => x.MainImage, () => mainImage)
                .Where(x => x.Id == serviceId)
                .SingleOrDefault();

Comment: Unlikely scenario, but it is important to note that you can create an "illegal access to loading collection" by inspecting members in the debugger, as on a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that joinalias wont eagerload the collections? that's what Fetch is for. Try this one instead

```
var service = UnitOfWork.CurrentSession.QueryOver<Service>()
    .Fetch(x => x.Images).Eager
    .Fetch(x => x.Videos).Eager
    .Where(x => x.Id == serviceId)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Update:

**illegal access to loading collection** could be thrown when

- session is closed when accessing not initialized collection
- mapping and collection type mismatch
- Database doesn't match

have you inspected the sql generated to see if NH tries to access nonexistant columns or columns on the wrong table?

Comment: Not true, JoinAlias does infect eagerly fetch the data.

Comment: really? i cant seem to get NH 3.1 to do so. it joins the childs but wont initialize the collection because maybe you are filtering on the alias and then not all childs of the collection would be there to initialize

Comment: thumbimage and mainImage different item.my items -> Videos and Images

Comment: @Firo - You need to specify the join type on the query. http://www.philliphaydon.com/2011/04/nhibernate-querying-relationships-are-depth/ see the last example where I specify LeftOuterJoin. That will initialize the collection.

Comment: working if remove images or videos. no inspected. i dont know :(